# Changing the drive of a database

Tags: restore, content-database

Ok so I have a database server. I went to create a new test site so created a web app and a site collection which obv created a content database. I then did a restore onto that site collection from another site collection. However half way through it stopped because there was not enough space in the drive where my database was. There is plenty of space in other drives on the server. Will I be able to copy over my db to one of these drives and do the restore again. Or will I need to change anything to tell it what drive the db is in

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint does not care about the which drive the db is but care about the space.

Drives are major concern of sql server. You have to configure that at sql level.you can add another drive to sql server. If the other drive have plenty of space, I would move all the db to that drive.  Either case sharepoint will fine

In order to safe move, simple detach the db from sharepoint.